# mascara aceitando números e , com jQuery Mask Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Galera queria saber como criar uma máscara no jQuery Mask Plugin para que o input aceite apenas números e virgula.

Para aceitar apenas número estou fazendo assim:

```
$('#valor').mask('#', {
    reverse: true
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vejo que deseja uma mascara para dinheiro, neste caso, mascaras baseadas em expressões regulares não são a melhor opção, entre utilize uma mascara especilizada.

[JQuery Mask Money](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#dinheiroComZero').maskMoney({ decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 2 });
  $('#dinheiroSemZero').maskMoney({ decimal: ',', thousands: '.', precision: 0 });
  $('#dinheiroVirgula').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ',', precision: 2 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <label>
    Com Centavos: 
    <input type="text" id="dinheiroComZero" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Sem Centavos:
    <input type="text" id="dinheiroSemZero" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Virgula como seperador: 
    <input type="text" id="dinheiroVirgula" />
  </label>
</div>
```

[Vanilla Masker](https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker)

```js
var dinheiro = document.getElementById("dinheiro");
VMasker(dinheiro).maskMoney({
  precision: 2,
  separator: ',',
  delimiter: '.',
  unit: 'R$',  
  zeroCents: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker/master/lib/vanilla-masker.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="dinheiro" />
```

No caso do `Vanilla Masker`, prefiro usar uma versão modificada, que faz uso do evento `input` ao invés do `keyup`.

Comment: não quero usar uma mascara para dinheiro, afinal so quero um input onde eu posso adicionar apenas números e virgulas. E acho que com o jQuery Mask Plugin da para fazer isso, afinal já utilizo ele no meu sistema.

Comment: @HugoBorges, você está tentando caçar como um gato, apesar de ter um cão ao seu dispor.

Answer (score 1):

Para aceitar números com virgula utilize

```
 $('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
```

Comment: não deu certo. preciso adicionar números assim 1,22,333,222,1,333,444,32

Comment: para numeros inteiros eu fiz isso `$('#valor').mask('###0', {
    reverse: true
});`

Comment: mais a virgula não funciona. Preciso adicionar números e virgula

Comment: Mas você precisa de um numero com mais de uma virgula?
Tem uma quantidade especifica de casas decimais que você precisa?

Comment: então não tem uma quantidade específica, e tenho que por várias virgulas. Vc sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Amigo, não sei se com jquery mask você irá conseguir.
No meu ambiente para tratar isso tive que trabalhar com REGEX.
Talvez para usar o Jquery mask, você terá que mexer no core do plugin (que não é recomendado). Talvez outra pessoa tenha uma solução melhor que o Regex

Comment: bom, então muito obrigado pela ajuda :) se eu achar a solução irei postar aqui.

Comment: Blz, mas tente não se focar no MASK, você pode fazer um script que permita entrar somente com numeros e virgula no seu input

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma função rapida em js puro para criar esta mascara:

```js
function calcularCustoEntrada(){

    inputPeso = document.getElementById('meuInput').value;
    inputPesoCorrigido = '';
    teclasValidas = '0123456789,';

    for(i=0; i<inputPeso.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<teclasValidas.length; j++){
            if(inputPeso[i] == teclasValidas[j]){
                inputPesoCorrigido += inputPeso[i];
            }
        }   
    }   

    document.getElementById('meuInput').value = inputPesoCorrigido;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="meuInput" onkeyup="calcularCustoEntrada()">
```